# Workings of TextGeometry parameters (protruding instead of extruding)

Tags: javascript, three.js

I mean to use TextGeometry to extrude a string into a 3D object. When setting params for the TextGeometry class, I did not get an extruded mesh, I got a protruded one. Since the geometry's parent class is ExtrudeGeometry, I found this strange (the workings of which are clear).

Context code:

```
const loader = new STLLoader();
        loader.load(URL.createObjectURL(stlFile), function (geometry) { //stlFile is the 3D object
            const material = new THREE.MeshNormalMaterial();
            const mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);

            var loadedFont; //font
            var extrudedGeometry; //textGeometry var
            var extrudedMaterial; // material type

            var fLoader = new FontLoader();
            fLoader.load('./app_files/Arial_Regular.json', function (font) {
                loadedFont = font;

                extrudedGeometry = new TextGeometry(extrudedText, { //extrudedText holds string to extrude
                    font: loadedFont, // loading font
                    size: 5, // Adjusting size
                    height: -10, // Adjust extrusion depth.
                    //params I've found that also made no difference
                    material: 0,
                    extrudeMaterial: 1,
                });

                extrudedMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: 0xffff });
                const extrudedMesh = new THREE.Mesh(extrudedGeometry, extrudedMaterial);
```

I've tried adjusting the parameters but the underlying mesh did not change as desired (to serve the function of extrusion) the height param adjusted only its orientation of its protrusion.

problem code block:

```
extrudedGeometry = new TextGeometry(extrudedText, { //extrudedText holds string to extrude
                    font: loadedFont, // loading font
                    size: 5, // Adjusting size
                    height: -10, // Adjust extrusion depth.
                    //params I've found that also made no difference
                    material: 0,
                    extrudeMaterial: 1,
                });
```